# How to modify/update dinamically by ajax the options of a select of Wordpress Gravity Forms AddOn Framework based

Tags: wordpress, add-on, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm building a **Add-On for Gravity Forms** in Wordpress using the [GravityForms Add-On Framework](https://docs.gravityforms.com/category/developers/php-api/add-on-framework/). I have a lot of settings fields where the user can set information that will be used to send to an API on the form submit. 3 of his settings as selects tha have dependencies. The second depends on the choice of the first, and the third depends on the choice of the second. So I need to populate new choices dynamically on the frontend. On the change of the choice of the first select I make a ajax call using javascript to the backend that consults the API and returns the results in a list of choices for the next select. Its all ok with that process.

My problem is: when we click the button to save the settings, the frontend selects aren't the same of to the backend.

What I need: To save the choices on the backend every change by the ajax call.

I tried to:

use the function save_form_settings

```
// #### SAVE THE NEW CHOICES ####
$form = $this->get_current_form(); // get the form
$settings = $this->get_form_settings( $form ); // get the settings
$settings['my_setting_field']['choices'] = $my_list; //modify the settings with the new choices
$this->save_form_settings($form, $settings);  //save the settings
```

I also tried to use maybe_save_form_settings()... [Here](http://inlinedocs.gravityhelp.com/source-class-GFAddOn.html#4758-4767) we can see all the AddOn class, but really I couldn't understand how to do it.

Can someone helpe me? The entire code is [here](https://github.com/danweb80/gravitforms_leadlovers).